# Python handling exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my program, I want to take in an input which should be a number.If the user inputs a string, however, the program returns an exception.I want the program set in such a way that the input is converted to int and then if the string is anything other than an int the program prints that "Stop writing please".Like for example:

```
   x=input("Enter a number")
        if int(x)=?:         #This line should check whether the integer conversion is possible
        print("YES")
        else                #This line should execute if the above conversion couldn't take place
        print("Stop writing stuff")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use try-except blocks:

```
x=input("Enter a number")
try:
    x = int(x)    # If the int conversion fails, the program jumps to the exception
    print("YES")  # In that case, this line will not be reached
except ValueError:
    print("Stop writing stuff")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a try-except block to catch the exceptional case, and inside there, print your statement. Something like this:

```
x=input("Enter a number")
try:
    x=int(x)
    print("YES") 
except: 
    print("Stop writing stuff")
```